# Javascript - move elements by pressing another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lets say I have a div with images, however not all have space to be displayed at same the time, so I used CSS property white-space: nowrap and overflow: hidden, so elements don't break into new lines or expand over div.

Now I need JavaScript technique that will allow me to move them left or right so user can reach these not visible images aswell. Think of it as a slider.

It should have two navigation buttons, left and right, by pressing each, images move in specific direction. Movement should be animated (not moving instantly, instead, they should move over specific period, frame by frame)

Here is jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rfLffev7/
(red and green div represent a button that should trigger functions)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="track">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: #500;
}

#track {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#track img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: #050;
}
```

Comment: For this specific problem, I tried class change, however it didn't go well, result is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use absolute positioning for that as the CSS will be simpler.  For the JavaScript, it's quite simple.

Here, I subtract 116px from the "margin-left" to move #track to the left and add 116px to #track to move it back to the right.  I have not added any "stops" at either end, so in theory you could keep scrolling indefinitely.

```
document.getElementById("left").onclick = function(){
  var currentPlace = parseInt(document.getElementById("track").style.marginLeft) || 0;
  document.getElementById("track").style.marginLeft = (currentPlace - 116) + "px"
}

document.getElementById("right").onclick = function(){
  var currentPlace = parseInt(document.getElementById("track").style.marginLeft) || 0;
  document.getElementById("track").style.marginLeft = (currentPlace + 116) + "px"
}
```

Here's a working example (using absolute positioning): http://jsfiddle.net/rfLffev7/1/

I also added an additional :nth-child(even) class to make it more obvious that the images are moving:

```
#track img:nth-child(even) {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Exactly that! But how would you make it to be smooth; animated?

Comment: You could add a CSS3 transition: transition:margin-left 300ms;  http://jsfiddle.net/rfLffev7/5/

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed! Thank you man!
Btw, how would you make a limit? Something like when you reach end of the line(#track), it dosn't go further.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the inner track using margins. For example, check the element for its margin value, then for the size of the image (or whatever distance you want to move the track), then add those two values together, then apply the new value to the track.

```
$('#right').click(function(){
var moveDistance = $('#track').find('img').width()
var moved = $('#track').css('marginLeft');
var moveIt = moveDistance - parseInt(moved)
$('#track').css('marginLeft', -moveIt);
});
```

I have updated your example with what I mean. The green button is rigged to move the distance of 1 image + the previous value of the element margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfLffev7/4/

You'll also need to make a few changes to your css to keep the other elements positions.

```
#container {
width: 600px;
height: 200px;
margin: 10px auto;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

#left {
width: 50px;
height: 200px;
left:0;
background: #500;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}

#track {
width: auto;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background: #333;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
}

#track img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#track img:nth-child(even) {
border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#right {
width: 50px;
height: 200px;
background: #050;
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```